# Why can't I get the output of a C++ program using Process in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, process, redirectstandardoutput

I've got a C++ program which uses `wprintf_s` function to print the results into the command line. But when I uses `Process` in C# to read the output of the program, I cannot get any words of it. However when I added a `fflush(stdout)` after the `wprintf_s` statement, I can finally read the standard output in my C# program.

The code I use to start the progress is:

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "FILENAME",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
proc.Start();
StringCollection values = new StringCollection();

proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) => {
    lock (values) {
        values.Add(args.Data);
    }
};
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Can anybody tell me why a `fflush(stdout)` would work?

Comment: Because it is being buffered.

Comment: @OldProgrammer if there isn't a `fflush`, the output will be always in the buffer?

Comment: I've had a similar issue with running a Perl script, it buffered stdout then flushed all at once into my C# app when the script had finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is being buffered in the C++ process and will remain so until the buffer is full or it is flushed, e.g. by calling `fflush()`, by closing the stream, or other OS dependant reasons.

`fflush()` just causes any data in the output buffer to be written to the stream.

If you don't want to explicitly call `fflush()`, you can consider setting unbuffered mode on the output stream by calling [`setbuf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setbuf/) with a NULL pointer for the second argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout, (char *)NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        fputs("hi there\n", stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Now the output will appear immediately.

Note that if `stdout` is a terminal, `setbuf(f, NULL)` is unnecessary as this is the default behaviour for terminal devices. If `stdout` is a pipe, then `setbuf(f, NULL)` will make it unbuffered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm wondering if whenever I use `Process` to launch a command-line program and redirect the output stream, the `stdout` of the program will be a pipe?

Comment: By "pipe" I was referring to the concept of the output of one process being connected to the input of another. Anyway, the buffering is happening in the child process, so disabling buffering in the child solves the problem. Possibly the redirect is implemented with pipes, but I'm not sufficiently expert with .NET to say for sure.